# Get Posts by Meta Values using checkbox

Tags: php, wordpress

In my wordpress theme i create two checkbox in sidebar for custom field value. Apple and Nokia are values for key name Brand.

**Now i need when i check a box or multiple box it show all relative post?**

> Here is input code,

```
<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="mobile" value="nokia"
<?php  
$args = array (
'meta_query'    => array(
    array(
        'key'   => 'brand',
        'value' => 'nokia'  
    ),
 ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>/> Nokia <br>


<input type="checkbox" name="mobile" value="apple"
<?php  
$args = array (
'meta_query'    => array(
    array(
        'key'   => 'brand',
        'value' => 'apple'  
    ),
 ),
);
?>/> Apple <br>
</form>
```

**This query is used to get post, How this is used in template file for showing checkbox result?**

```
<?php $query = new WP_Query( $args );
     if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
 while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $query->the_post();
   get_template_part('content');
 }
} else {
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: I suggest you to use AJAX call for this thing. :)

Comment: plz provide me more detail are any link about AJAX, which make it easy for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code

this should be in your template

```
    <form id='test'>
<input type="checkbox" name="t[]" value="Nokia" class="br">
<input type="checkbox" name="t[]" value="Sony" class="br">
<div class="mobile_brand">

</div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('.br').click(function(){
            jQuery('.contents').remove();
            var checked = jQuery('#test').serialize();
            jQuery.ajax({
                url:"<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
                data:"action=call_post&"+checked,
                success:function(obj){
                     var render_data = "<div class='contents'>";

                    // This is to watch your json object
                    console.log(obj);   

                    for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++)
                    {
                        console.log(obj[i].post_title);
                        render_data+="<h4>"+obj[i].post_title+"</h4>";
                        render_data+="<p>"+obj[i].post_content+"</p>";
                    }
                    render_data+="</div>";
                    jQuery(render_data).appendTo('.mobile_brand');

                }
            });
        })
    });
</script>
```

This should be in your `functions.php`

```
add_action('wp_ajax_call_post','call_post');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_call_post','call_post');
function call_post(){
    $test = $_REQUEST['mobile'];

    $args = array(
        'post_type'  => 'post',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'brand',
                'value'   => $test,
                // 'compare' => 'IN',
            ),
        ),
    );

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
wp_send_json($query->posts);

}
```

This is just sample code for you. You need to render data by iterating JSON.

Comment: @FarooqAhmad sorry for delay. I have made it for you. Remember this is just sample code for your information. :) If you like it then accept and give +1

Comment: plz explain this line its from script  'url:"<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>"'

Comment: In wordpress AJAX calling is a little different https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins you can go through this link.

Comment: Not needed because we are doing it with ajax so. If WP_Query was in our template file then we need loop to show results.

Comment: i read many tutorial and google search, but still unable to filter meta data.. Is there need to attached any additional file, code or script? To make it workable

Comment: I didn't get you. Like what type of meta data filter you are doing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120918/discussion-between-milan-kyada-and-farooq-ahmad).

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for [get_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/). It's used in the loop as in the below example. Your loop is probably located in the file that contains the "content" template part.

```
get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'brand', true );
```