# HTML <input> value support multiple custom field values

Tags: php, html, ajax, wordpress, checkbox

I create a custom field AJAX Post filter, its filter values correct way.. Now i need to make it more optional after that it support multiple values of one custom field..

**Working This way:**

> Custom field **Key & Value  ===>    display = 4** ... This is for 1st input others value will be 5,6 and 7.

```
<div class="display">   
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="display" value="4" class="br"> 4 inch  </li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="display" value="5" class="br"> 5 inch  </li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="display" value="6" class="br"> 6 inch </li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="display" value="7" class="br"> 7 inch </li>
</div>
```

**Required That way:**

> Custom field **Key & Value  ===>    display = 3.5**  .. for first input

```
<div class="display">   
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="display" value="1.0 - 4" class="br"> Below - 4.0 inch  </li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="display" value="4.1 - 5" class="br"> 4.1  - 5 inch  </li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="display" value="5.1 - 6" class="br"> 5.1  - 6.0 inch </li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="display" value="6.1 - 8" class="br"> 6.1  - above inch  </li>
</div>
```

**Required in More Detail:**

When I put value **`1 to 4`** in custom field then first checkbox filter it.

How to manage in input tag value **`1 - 4`**  that will support custom field values that will also between **`1 - 4`**?

In others words inside input tag value support multiple values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using, for example in your `<input>` a value of `'1.0 - 4'` why you don't just put the max value. So instead you will have:

```html
<div class="display">   
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="display" value="4" class="br"> Below - 4.0 inch  </li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="display" value="5" class="br"> 4.1  - 5 inch  </li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="display" value="6" class="br"> 5.1  - 6.0 inch </li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="display" value="9" class="br"> 6.1  - above inch  </li>
</div>
```

Then after you will create another **custom-field** in your post, for example **`'screen'`**, in which you will put the real screen value (to be displayed above the phone in your template).

> Then, you will use **`'display'`custom field only with your ajax filter**.

---

Related author threads:

- [Get posts with Ajax posts filter with multi selection checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39130444/get-posts-with-ajax-posts-filter-with-multi-selection-checkboxes)
- [Get Posts by Meta Values using checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38924223/get-posts-by-meta-values-using-checkbox)
- [Use multiple 'relation' arguments in AJAX post filter function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39296734/use-multiple-relation-arguments-in-ajax-post-filter-function)